# firestore changes not triggering

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I feel like I should at least be seeing an error or .. if uncharacteristically lucky, success. I have an event setup on `/sampleData/metrics/{uid}/{document}`, which you can see here:

[image: dashboard - functions]

note that the Triggers *do not* contain the leading `/`. On my first *deploy*, it didn't have it specified in the code either. I changed that when I didn't see an invocation the first time I tested, but that text has not changed in *console.firebase.google.com* there... however, the subsequent deploys do look complete:

```
=== Deploying to 'THIS PROJECT'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing . directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged . (172.19 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: . folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function onAddLocation(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function onAddMetric(us-central1)...
✔  functions[onAddLocation(us-central1)]: Successful update operation. 
✔  functions[onAddMetric(us-central1)]: Successful update operation. 

✔  Deploy complete!

Please note that it can take up to 30 seconds for your updated functions to propagate.
Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/THIS PROJECT/overview
✨  Done in 51.23s.
```

And we can also see that my sample app is adding data there:

[image: dashboard - database]

But as I add data, I don't see my functions being triggered. The count on the functions -> usage tab remains at 0, even minutes later:

[image: dashboard - functions - usage]

My functions are in node 8 and make use of *async/await*, but both package.json and firebase.json specify

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8"
},
```

## notes:

added a screenshot of the usage tab to show that `console.log` probably won't say anything.

Comment: You can make use of `console.log()` in your functions, and then click over to the Logs tab in the Functions dashboard to verify if they're being triggered or not.  It typically takes about 30 seconds after an event to see the log displayed in the web dashboard.

Comment: @miles_b `console.log` calls probably require that the function is invoked before they will happen though.. am I wrong about that in some way??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Functions dashboard shows a trigger "ref.write" it means that your Cloud Function is triggered when you write to the **Realtime Database** and not to **Cloud Firestore**. They are two different database services offered by Firebase.

You have to adapt your code following this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0

For example like:

```
exports.firestoreTrigger = functions.firestore
  .document('/sampleData/metrics/{uid}/{document}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const msgData = snapshot.data();
    console.log(msgData);
    return null;
  });
```

Comment: thank you. just a note for anyone who made the same mistake that I did,  on redeploy after changing the trigger, I got `⚠  functions: failed to update function onAddLocation HTTP Error: 400, Change of function trigger type or event provider is not allowed` -- so I had to delete the functions from the console first.